# Turn-based trading game set in space, from the 1990s

Tags: gaming, identify-this-game

This is certainly a long shot... this game has evaded my searching for years and I would love to have this mysterious game named once and for all.

- It came out prior to 1997 (possibly earlier this is just when I discovered it)
- It was a turn-based (hot-seat) game
- It was set in space with a dozen or so planets
- At the start each player chose their 'spaceship' with some being faster/more fuel efficient while others had more capacity. (One of the spaceships looked like a brain)
- The focus was finance / strategy. You would buy/sell resources. The value of resources would go up/down like a stock-market.
- Your turn would end when you ended your go or decided to travel to another planet.
- Depending on your spaceship some planets required several hops (if you wanted to get from planet A to B you may need to go via planet C thus taking an extra turn)
- Mid turn you could be intercepted by a NPC who requests your help. Promising payment 50/50 chance he would rob you if you decided to help.
- The demo version would end after a fixed number of turns

Comment: Was this a BBS game? Any of these ring any bells? https://www.reddit.com/r/Eve/comments/2q1pbt/any_other_old_fogies_out_there_remember_major_bbs/

Comment: It maybe have also been ported as a BBS game but I only remember it as a local (windows) game. Thanks for the link but unfortunately it doesn't look like it's any of those

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm guessing you're talking about [Gazillionaire Deluxe](http://www.old-games.com/download/8787/gazillionaire-deluxe).  It's a space trading game that came out in 1996, supported multiple players, and set in a universe with 7 planets. Notably on this screenshot taken from Old-Games.com, one of the spaceships looks like a brain:

[image: Gazillionaire Deluxe spaceship selection screenshot]

Comment: Wow!!! You are 100% correct, thank you sir! Without exaggeration I've wondered what the name was for years!

Comment: Gazillionaire was actually kind of a rip-off (or at least a "recycled idea") of *Spaceward Ho!"* for (initially) the Classic Mac that came out years earlier (1990 vs. 1996)

Comment: @tofro Not really. Spaceward Ho! is 4X space game, a genre that got its start on computers with Reach for the Stars in 1983. Gazillionaire Deluxe is a space trading game, a genre that goes back to 1974's Star Trader.